# ggplot2 - boxplot multiple data.frames while staying in order

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2, boxplot

I apologize if this is more for SO instead of CV.

I am attempting to include a second boxplot into an existing boxplot that is ordered by the mean of the values plotted.  When I include the boxplot from the second data.frame (representing a control sample to the other plots), the original plot looses its ordering.

Below is an example:

```
x1 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 0, 100), "siteno" = "X1") #mean = 50.3
x2 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 200, 450), "siteno" = "X2") #mean = 322.4
x3 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 50, 150), "siteno" = "X3") #mean = 97.8
xData <- rbind(x1,x2,x3)
xData$siteno <- with(xData, reorder(siteno, V1, mean))

zData <- data.frame("V1" = runif(300, 0, 450), "siteno" = "Z1") #mean = 224.2

#orders xData correctly 
ggplot(xData, aes(x = siteno , y = V1)) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point") +
geom_boxplot (aes(fill=siteno), alpha=.5, width=1, position = position_dodge(width = 1),  outlier.colour = "dark gray", outlier.size = 1)
```

this produces the below plot with x variables correctly ordered by mean:

[image: correctly ordered boxplots]

If I try the code below to add the control data, the order of the x variables is lost:

```
x1 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 0, 100), "siteno" = "X1") #mean = 50.3
x2 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 200, 450), "siteno" = "X2") #mean = 322.4
x3 <- data.frame("V1" = runif(100, 50, 150), "siteno" = "X3") #mean = 97.8
xData <- rbind(x1,x2,x3)
xData$siteno <- with(xData, reorder(siteno, V1, mean))

zData <- data.frame("V1" = runif(300, 0, 450), "siteno" = "Z1") #mean = 224.2

#orders xData correctly 
ggplot(xData, aes(x = siteno , y = V1)) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point") +
geom_boxplot (aes(fill=siteno), alpha=.5, width=1, position = position_dodge(width = 1), outlier.colour = "dark gray", outlier.size = 1) +
geom_boxplot(data=zData, aes(x = siteno , y = V1))
```

this produces the following plot with no ordering of the x variables:
[image: incorrectly ordered boxplots]

The point of my graph is to show the test values ordered by their mean and then have the control values boxplot off to the right for visual reference. I imagine there could be a solution that combines the xData and zData dataframes; I am willing to try that if there are some suggestions.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not ask on the ggplot list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use two data frame to combine data in one plot original levels (and order) is lost and new levels than combine data from both data frames are used. You don't get this behavior for fill values because you don't provide fill argument for the second data frame. But for the discrete x scale both data frames are combined and new levels are `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and `Z1`.

Without making one data frame from all values you can use `scale_x_discrete()` and then in argument `limits=` use function `levels()` to get original order of levels of `siteno` and combine it with `Z1` for reference level.

```
ggplot(xData, aes(x = siteno , y = V1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point") +
  geom_boxplot (aes(fill=siteno), alpha=.5, outlier.colour = "dark gray", 
                                                  outlier.size = 1) +
  geom_boxplot(data=zData, aes(x = siteno , y = V1))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(levels(xData$siteno),"Z1"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution and for a great explanation.  `scale_x_discreet` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

why not add them all in one `data.frame` and order all 4 levels in that?

```
data2 <- rbind(xData, zData)
ggplot(data2, aes(x = siteno , y = V1)) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point") +
geom_boxplot (aes(fill=siteno), alpha=.5, width=1, 
              position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
              outlier.colour = "dark gray", outlier.size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this helpful idea.  I used the previous solution so that I could have more control over the appearance of the control sample boxplot.  But undoubtedly, your approach will com in handy down the road.

Answer (score 0):

capture the desired order, eg, something like:

```
 ord <- xvars[order(mean(xvars))]
```

Then use `scale_x_discrete()`

Comment: Thank you Ricardo.  Your solution, like Didzis's above worked great.